# Tensorflow variable and constant difference when used for shape

Tags: tensorflow

In `W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, -1.0, 0.0))`, I tried the following three data types for `shape`:

```
shape = tf.constant([1])  # 1
shape = [1]               # 2
shape = tf.Variable([1])  # 3
```

Then I call:

```
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(W))
```

Both `1` and `2` outputs correctly, something like `[-0.25340891]`. However, `3` gives me

> ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("random_uniform:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)

A complete code sample:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# shape = tf.constant([1])  # 1
# shape = [1]               # 2
shape = tf.Variable([1])  # 3

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, -1.0, 0.0))

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

print(sess.run(W))
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your example does not work because of two reasons:

1. When you initialize W with random, the init value should have shape specified, but the shape is not specified, as it is a variable itself and not a constant. Adding validate_shape=False sidesteps this issue.
2. initialize_all_variables() runs all inits in parallel, but you need to initialize 'shape' variable first. Explicitly initializing variables in required order solves this issue.

Working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

shape = tf.Variable([1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape, -1.0, 0.0), validate_shape=False)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(shape.initializer)
sess.run(W.initializer)

print(sess.run(W))
```